# duplicate key value violates unique constraint Error using sql_constraints

Tags: odoo

I have used as

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('bpv_uniq', 'unique (branch_id,product_id,product_tmpl_id)', "There are Other Reference Purchase Price in same branch, please change branch"),
]
```

I have removed this code and upgrade module. But on data entry still gives the following error;

duplicate key value violates unique constraint "reference_price_uniq"
DETAIL: Key (branch_id,product_id,product_tmpl_id)=(2,31,27) already exists.

Please guide.

Comment: You have a similar SQL constraint named `price_uniq` on model `reference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to override the constraint to check nothing instead.

```
_sql_constraints = [('bpv_uniq', 'CHECK(1==1)', "There are Other Reference Purchase Price in same branch, please change branch"),]
```